# Regex split string on multiple separators with quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I have the following string (the double quotes are part of the string):

```
"abc def ghi" "%1" "%2"
```

So the string starts with a double quote, each segment is separated by `" "` and the string ends with a double quote again. I would like to split this into:

```
abc def ghi
%1
%2
```

I tried the following: `"(^\")|(\" \")|(\"$)"` but that doesn't give me the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't complicate it. Just use a string split:

```
        string test = "\"abc def ghi\" \"%1\" \"%2\"";
        var splits = test.Split(new string[]{"\" \"","\""},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var split in splits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(split);
        }
```

( removes the superfluous / empty entries as well)

Comment: Better than my answer, liked it.

Comment: Exactly the result I want :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"(.*?)\"");
```

Results:

http://rubular.com/r/lXbDIpkRRQ

Comment: This is your answer using a `Regex`. Nice :].

Comment: This works but the result is an array of 7 strings: `["", "abc def ghi", " ", "%1", " ", "%2", ""]`. I'd like to get a result with 3 strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "\"abc def ghi\" \"%1\" \"%2\"";
string[] splittedStrings = s.Split('"');
string a = splittedStrings[1];
string b = splittedStrings[3];
string c = splittedStrings[5];
```

Comment: Like this because it's a very simple solution. However, I want a result that only contains 3 strings, not 7...

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg - Look at my variation of the split.